# How to override Typography colorPrimary in Link component Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to use Link component https://material-ui.com/api/link/ and I want to set my own colors for primary and secondary, but I can see it uses Typography to set that. How to override it? With code below doesnt work

```
const typographyStyle = withStyles({
    root: {
        colorPrimary: {
            color: ColorsTheme.primary.default
        }
    }
});

const StyledLink = withStyles(() => ({
}))(MaterialLink);

const Link = props => (
    <StyledLink TypographyClasses={typographyStyle} {...props} />
);

export default Link;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example showing two different ways of doing this. The first approach (`CustomLink`) targets the [Typography Global class names](https://material-ui.com/api/typography/#css). The second approach (`CustomLink2`) uses `makeStyles` to create classes that are passed in to the `TypographyClasses` prop of `Link`.

```
import React from "react";
import MuiLink from "@material-ui/core/Link";
import { withStyles, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const CustomLink = withStyles({
  root: {
    "&.MuiTypography-colorPrimary": {
      color: "green"
    },
    "&.MuiTypography-colorSecondary": {
      color: "purple"
    }
  }
})(MuiLink);

const useTypographyStyles = makeStyles({
  colorPrimary: {
    color: "orange"
  },
  colorSecondary: {
    color: "brown"
  }
});

const CustomLink2 = (props) => {
  const typographyClasses = useTypographyStyles();
  return <MuiLink TypographyClasses={typographyClasses} {...props} />;
};
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MuiLink color="primary">Default Primary</MuiLink>
      <br />
      <MuiLink color="secondary">Default Secondary</MuiLink>
      <br />
      <CustomLink color="primary">Custom Primary</CustomLink>
      <br />
      <CustomLink color="secondary">Custom Secondary</CustomLink>
      <br />
      <CustomLink2 color="primary">Custom 2 Primary</CustomLink2>
      <br />
      <CustomLink2 color="secondary">Custom 2 Secondary</CustomLink2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit customize Link colors]

Related documentation: https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested?v=v10.5.0#use--to-reference-selector-of-the-parent-rule

Comment: Yeah, thanks, that is what I finally did, but I was hoping that there exists other way :)

Comment: @user0810 I've added a second approach to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be by overriding css rules (not recommended),

Better way of doing it would be by using palette of Mui
( [Link to the docs](https://material-ui.com/system/palette/#palette) )

**But beware if you change your palette it will reflect in your whole app, meaning the color of other mui components will change**

Comment: Thats why I dont want to cahnge in the whole palette, only in this component

Comment: You can just inspect the particular element and check the `className` and then override the css rules by using `!important`

Comment: That is what I start doing, but I was hoping there is nicer way

Comment: Same here like there should something like custom colours option in the palette. Maybe you can try using `createStyles` method and then make use of `useStyles`. Now you can change colour directly.